# Issue with select and ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs, filter, unique, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've just started playing with Angular, and I'm having a hard time understanding certain things here. I wanted to set up a list of products, which belong to different categories. Some products are in the same category, like so :

```
$scope.products = [
  {'name': 'Product 1', 'cat':'Cat 1'},
  {'name': 'Product 2', 'cat':'Cat 2'},
  {'name': 'Product 3', 'cat':'Cat 2'},
  {'name': 'Product 4', 'cat':'Cat 3'},
  {'name': 'Product 5', 'cat':'Cat 3'},
  {'name': 'Product 6', 'cat':'Cat 2'},
];
```

I was able to create a `<select>` which merges the same categories in order to avoid duplicates, thanks to the unique filter from AngularUI. Here is the code :

```
<select ng-model="query" ng-options="c.cat for c in products | unique:'cat'">
    <option value="0">Default</option>
</select>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in products | filter:query">
        {{c.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to display the results in a list according to the category I've selected. But when I try to do so, the only product returned in the list will be the first one inside the category. I've created a Fiddle with my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/F7Hvq/3/.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some mistakes:

- The `<select>` will choose the entire product. So `| filter:query` will keep the thing that matches the product, i.e. the first product of the category in the array. I'd suggest you write it as:

  ```
  <select ng-model="query" ng-options="c.cat as c.cat for c in products | unique:'cat'">
  ```

  ...so as to select the `cat` field.
- Then the `| filter:query` does not know by what property to filter; change it as `| filter:{cat:query}`

You will have to do something special, if no selection means no filter; currently it will match no products. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7ZCg/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed. I was indeed suspecting that my `ng-options` were not set at the right level, but couldn't figure out how to fix it. Makes perfect sense now that you explained it! As for the "no products" issue, I just removed the 0 value to make it work.